# PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher is Not working in android MotoG Edit text

Tags: android, android-edittext, phone-number, textwatcher, country

In android `phonenumberformattingtext` watcher is not working for Moto-G Mobile , but it is working fine in ( nexus -7, nexus-9, nexus-6 , nexus-4) but it is not working in Moto -G please help.

My code is:

```
phoneNumber.addTextChangedListener(this);
phoneNumber.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter , new InputFilter.LengthFilter(14)});
alternativePhoneNumber.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter , new InputFilter.LengthFilter(14)});
phoneNumber.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher());
alternativePhoneNumber.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher());
```

Comment: did you check your language locale that set in your language setting ?

Comment: Have had the same issue, but after removing android:digits="1234567890+" it gone.

Answer (score 9):

its late but this will definitely help to future viewer.

```
mPhoneText.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher());
```

this is not work in 21 or higher api. so you should wrap in api lvl condition like this.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            mPhoneText.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher("US"));
        }else {
            mPhoneText.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher());
        }
```

and dont forget to set `inputType="phone"`

i tested in moto g4 plus.

Answer (score 5):

check your language locale that set in your phone's language settings... set it to English (United states).

Answer (score 1):

Ensure `android:inputType="phone"` is set on your `TextView` in your xml.